# Installing JRuby with RVM fails on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: java, macos, rubygems, jruby

I'm on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.3).

When I say "rvm install jruby", I get the following:

```
> rvm install jruby
jruby-1.6.7 - #fetching
jruby-1.6.7 - #extracted to /Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/src/jruby-1.6.7 (already extracted)
Building Nailgun
jruby-1.6.7 - #installing to /Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7
jruby-1.6.7 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/gemsets/)
Copying across included gems
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 57301
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/bin/sh: line 1: 23840 Abort trap: 6           /Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby extconf.rb 2>&1
ERROR:  Error installing jruby-launcher:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

                /Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby extconf.rb
                ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
                ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
                JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
                FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)


                Gem files will remain installed in /Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/jruby-launcher-1.0.12-java for inspection.
                Results logged to /Users/daniel.cox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/jruby-launcher-1.0.12-java/./gem_make.out
```

What's going on here? It seems it's trying to start some server twice, and during build of "jruby-launcher". Why would it be starting a server at all?

The same installation works fine on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine.

Thanks,

-Daniel

Comment: Also, every time I run ruby after "rvm use jruby", it says "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 57301".